# Manage leap seconds in time management

Tags: c++, time, leap-second

I just learned that a [leap second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) will be added at the end of this month (june 2015). I'm a little bit affraid about that, because I manage my own time class. I'm not sure it's robust enough.

I created a class `Instant` working with a `unsigned long long int` member variable `ms` which is the number of milliseconds from `01/01/1600` at `0:00:00`.

When I want to get the current time, I call this function :

```
void Instant::setCurrentTime()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    this->ms = NBR_DAYS_TO_EPOCH; // 135140
    this->ms *= NBR_SECONDS_IN_DAY; // 86400
    this->ms += tv.tv_sec;
    this->ms *= NBR_MILLISECONDS_IN_SECOND; // 1000
    this->ms += tv.tv_usec/1000;
}
```

My first question is : **How leap seconds affect this number ? Is it already taken into account in the `tv.tv_sec` value ? How ?**

My second question is about the conversion to human-readable format. I don't post it here because my function is quite huge (I can post it if required), but the idea is the following :

- I first compute the number of seconds in the current day, and then the number of minutes and hours ;
- I compute the number of days before the current day ;
- Then I compute the number of cycles of 400 years (periodic process), the number of cycles of 100 years in the current cycle of 400 years, and the number of cycles of 4 years in the current cycle of 4 years ;
- From that, I deduce the year (leap or not), the month, the day, and the day of the week ;
- Then I check if the summer time is activated, and I update the values according to the zone (europe, usa before 2007, usa from 2007) ;
- All of that without taking into account the 25 leap seconds added from 1970.

For the moment, my class is not able to say "we are `30/06/2015` at `23:59:60`", because my number of seconds is limited to `59`. But also because I don't know how to manage that. what could be a good way ?

Comment: out of interest, why do you `manage my own time class` ? is this academic or in-use ?

Comment: You do know that a number of leap seconds have been added over the years? How do you handle them?

Comment: @amdixon: it was academic, but I use it in a real application now. Actually, it's also used as a time object in several situations, for logs time, durations, but also as a mathematical time value.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: yes. As I said, I saw that 25 leap seconds were already added from 1970. But actually I don't manage them for the moment. I would like to upgrade that.

Comment: you could introduce a patch_time function before returning your time data. could you expand on the exact details of the 25 leap seconds so that those of us who are time illiterate can help

Comment: I agree, but for the moment I don't well understand how the system already manage that. Is the `tv_sec` value already including these leap seconds ? How can I know if the system is aware of the next one ? And if not, why my hour seems correct when I print the current time ? The list of the 25 leap seconds already added is in link I provided (the right column with green cells).

Comment: The `gettimeofday` function returns the wall clock, if it's synchronized (e.g. through NTP) then it should already have the leap seconds.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: actually, I'm not sure, because my hour is correct (the same than the system) without taking the leap seconds into account.

Comment: The computer you run on, is the time synchronized from a central server? If it is, you most likely have the correct time, with leap seconds, already. The problem you have then is that if you want to get an *earlier* data through your system, as then you have to *deduct* the leap seconds yourself.

Comment: Then the value of `tv_sec` will change from `t` to `t+2` when passing the end of june due to the synchronization of my computer, but the value of `tv_sec` as the number of seconds from epoch doesn't include the leap seconds added, and the the epoch time "moves" one second later relatively to the current time. Right ?